# Ruby: Managing file paths within required classes

Tags: ruby

Suppose a Ruby project with the following structure...

```
project/
|-- data
|   `-- data.yaml
|-- lib
|   |-- project
|   |   `-- myclass.rb
|   `-- project.rb
```

Within lib/project/myclass.rb, I load data/data.yaml as shown in the example below...

```
def MyClass
  data = YAML::load(File.open('../../data/data.yaml'))
  # Other stuff..
end
```

Within lib/project.rb, I include project/myclass.rb

If project.rb is run, the following error will be thrown...

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ../../data/data.yaml
```

In order to get around this, I have to update the file path used in myclass.rb so that it is relative to the root or the lib directory...

```
../data/data.yaml
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data like this:

```
filename = File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'data', 'data.yaml'
data = YAML::load File.open filename
```

The way you are currently doing it is kind of bad because it imposes requirements on the user's current directory when he runs your code.

Alternatively, you can [embed the YAML data at the end of your ruby file using the `__END__` keyword](http://shifteleven.com/articles/2009/02/09/useless-ruby-tricks-data-and-__end__).